# compiling with a .h file with gcc and a self-sorting list

Tags: c, list, filesystems, header-files

I've got a little problem with an exercise I have to finish. We have to implement a recurisve "ls" program which prints out the "n" biggest files. But there are some problems.

1)

I have three files, main.c, list.c and list.h. In list.h I have included string.h ,stdio.h,stdlib.h,declared a struct (char* filename,long long filesize and struct element* next) and two methods (append,printlist). In list.c I have included list.h and implemented the two methods append and printlist. In main.c I have included unistd.h,dirent.h, sys/stat.h and list.h.

When I try to compile it with "gcc main.c" I get the error "used of undeclared methods append and printlist" but if I'm using Eclipse it builds just fine. How can I solve this?

Exact errors

```
/tmp/ccLbHnqR.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x189): undefined reference to `printliste'
/tmp/ccLbHnqR.o: In function `ftop':
main.c:(.text+0x1f6): undefined reference to `append'
```

2)

To implement the functionality I tried to use a self-sorting list, i.e. go through the list until the last value that is bigger than the new value, then set the pointer of the new value to the pointer of the last value and the pointer of the last value is the new value.

In theory it should work, but in practice it isn't.

The append methods looks like this

```
void append(struct element **lst, char* filename, long long filesize){
    struct element *newElement;
    struct element *lst_iter = *lst;

    newElement = malloc(sizeof(*newElement)); // create new element
    newElement->filename = filename;
    newElement->filesize = filesize;
    newElement->next = NULL; // important to find the end of the list

    if ( lst_iter != NULL ) { // if elements are existing
        //if our element is bigger than the first element
        if(lst_iter->filesize < newElement->filesize){
            newElement->next = lst_iter;
            *lst = newElement;
        } else {
            while(lst_iter->next != NULL){
                if(lst_iter->filesize > newElement->filesize) lst_iter = lst_iter->next;
                else break;
            }
            newElement->next = lst_iter->next;
            lst_iter->next = newElement;
        }           
    }
    else // if the list is empty our value is the new value
    *lst=newElement;
}
```

I'm using this method from my "ftop" method, which gets a directory, adds every file in this directory to the list and for each directory it calls "ftop" again.

```
void ftop(char* path){
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;

    //open the directory
    dir = opendir(path);
    if (dir != NULL) {
        //for each file/directory in it
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            struct stat st;
            //if it is a file, append it to the list
            if(S_ISREG(st.st_mode)){
                append(&list, ent->d_name, st.st_size);
            } else {
                //if it is a directory, use recursion
                ftop(ent->d_name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't get it why it isn't working. I know you don't want to do the homework of others, but I would be thankful for every hint you could give me.

P.s.: If you want the full code

[main.c](http://pastebin.com/u8HED4CR)
[list.c](http://pastebin.com/fKR8F8mM)

Comment: I bet I know where this homework comes from ;)

Comment: Please, post separate questions as separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
gcc -o main main.c list.c
```

that is — specify both files.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the the first problem (well I had a few includes wrong too, had to include stdlib and stdio in the list.h file)

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you have two problems :) I thought you're going into unnecessary explanation :) You should've posted two questions. I'll try to read the second, though I feel sleeepy :)

Comment: "In theory it should work, but in practice it isn't." — can you elaborate on that, so I don't have to read the whole code? :)

Comment: I try to. The first problem is, the method is skipping some values. For example, I created test1,...,test6 on my Desktop, with different sizes. But it skipped test4. The other problem is, for every file I'm looking at, I get the same size (for example test1 = 13937605, test2 = 13937605 ...)

Comment: First, `struct stat st; if(S_ISREG(st.st_mode)){` you do not call `stat` on the file.

Comment: Second, you may put debug prints here and there to get the picture of what's going on :)

Comment: Third, you code is very complicated, for instance, this `while(..) { if(..) .. else break; }`, would be tons shorter and therefore readable if you used `for`-loop, for instance. Or at the very least, inverse condition and put it as `if(..) break`.

Comment: Okay I changed to code in the while loop to if((stat(ent->d_name,&st)) == 0){if(st.st_mode & S_IFDIR){ftop(ent->d_name))} if(st.st_mode & S_IFREG){ append(&list,ent->d_name,st.st_size); }}

Now I have the right value, but it appends one file multiple times. Do I have to delete/remove/free stat at the end of the loop?

Comment: No, you don't. First thing that I see is wrong is that you have consecutive `if()` and not `if-else-if` chain. That may sure have some side effects. Second, I already told you about debugging, but you stick to bugging ;-) (no offense, couldn't resist).

Comment: finally, after a long day i found out what the heck was wrong
if i used only `ent->d_name` it didn't work, so i created a new variable which contained the absolute filepath, now it finally works.

Comment: Well, `ent->d_name` has the name of the file, not path, that's true. Congrats! :)